# Using EF Core, how to update database's newly created schema within code?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I created new schema within code using EF Core in Postgres. But then I need to migrate my migrations to new created schema (not "public" schema) at runtime. And all this is in one dataContext.

```
string command = $"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {name} AUTHORIZATION CURRENT_USER";
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(command);
```

I create new schemas at runtime with this command.

and then tried running:

```
dataContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Have you created any migrations? The schema generation code could go in the initial migration

Comment: yes. I have initial migration file, but it only migrates to "public" schema. what if I want to migrate these migrations to another schema?